# How do I enable Ati Radeon 9200 drivers so I can use Unity?

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, radeon, hp-pavilion

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my HP pavillion ZX500 with the Ati Radeon 9200 Graphics card. It works fine right now but the only problem is that the Unity desktop doesnt come on. It makes me have to use the classis one and the only reason I installed linux is to use unity. Does it need hardware acceleration for Unity?

I installed it on my PC and liked it so much I installed it on my laptop. I have heard there are drivers for ati cards in linux. I am new to linux, can anybody tell my how to get the right drivers or enable Unity?

Answer (score 1):

To check if your graphics card and driver can support unity-3d you can run the following in a terminal:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

On a new install, by default, the Open-Source driver is selected.

There maybe an ATI proprietary driver available - ensure you are connected to the internet and look at System - Additional Drivers.  If there is an ATI driver offered to you to be activated, then click on the "Activate" button.

If both unity_support_test reports unity-3d is not available and if there are no additional drivers you can install, your recommended option is to install the `unity-2d` package available in the Software Center.

In October, the version of unity-2d will be much closer -in terms of capability - to unity-3d and thus is a viable alternative.